# Getting worse result using keras 2 than keras 1

Tags: python, keras, mse

I ran the same code (with the same data) on CPU first using keras 1.2.0 and then keras 2.0.3 in both codes keras is with TensorFlow backend and also I used sklearn for model selection, plus pandas to read data.

I was surprised when I got the MSE(Mean squared error) of 42 using keras 2.0.3 and 21 using keras 1.2.0. Can someone pls explain to me why this is happening? Why I am getting more error using keras 2? Thanks

PS. This result is after editing the code to keras 2 standard. for example in Dense I change keras 1 code to keras 2 standard.

Answer (score 1):

Is really the MSE increased, or is it the *loss*? If you use regularizers, this may not be the same (even when using `mean_squared_error` as loss function), since the regularizer gives a [penalty to the loss](https://keras.io/regularizers/).

I think earlier versions of keras just gave you the MSE, now they show the loss. This *could* explain your observation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some default values that have changed from Keras 1.2.
You should check the default values for you 1.2 code, and set the same value for your new code.

Answer (score 0):

Keras 1 vs 2 has a lot of changes. Specifically the functions have many altered keyword arguments, your Keras 1 code is pretty worthless if your trying to run it after updating to Keras 2. Either downgrade back to version 1.2.0 or I would suggest going [here](https://keras.io/) and editing your code accordingly.